# Sitecore Powershell Deserialization - Core DB

Tags: c#, powershell, serialization, sitecore, sitecore7

I wanted to deserialize some Core Db items. I have created Serialization Packages and I tried to deserialize it with the PS Command :

> Deserialize-Item -Recurse -Database "core" -Path
>   "C:\serialization\core\sitecore\content\Applications\WebEdit" -Root
>   "C:\serialization"

When I execute this command, it tries to create some folders but it cant find the template for 'Folder', because it resides in the master database.

When I remove the -Database "core" option, it cant find the database, so in both attempts, I could not get Core DB folders deserialied with PS Script.

Does anyone have an idea, how I can deserialize Core DB Folders with script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I've noticed is that you're missing trailing `\` character in the `Root` parameter in your command. It should be `"C:\serialization\"` instead of `"C:\serialization"`. It should work without `Database` parameter. The code that works for me looks like this:

```
deserialize-item -Recurse -Path "C:\serialization\core\sitecore\content\Applications\WebEdit" -Root "C:\serialization\"
```

If it doesn't work for you, try to switch to `core:` before executing the script:

```
cd core:
deserialize-item -Recurse -Path "C:\serialization\core\sitecore\content\Applications\WebEdit" -Root "C:\serialization\"
```

Here is a blog post explaining [serialization and deserialization with Sitecore Powershell Extensions](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/serialization-and-deserialization-with-sitecore-powershell-extensions/).

Comment: The missing trailing \ character was the problem. It works when I add \ at the end. Thanks